# Is it possible to monitor kubernetes with Prometheus & Grafana that run outside of of the k8s cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose, prometheus, grafana, monitoring

My place has a k8s cluster running on DigitalOcean, I was tasked to create app in virtual machine (with DigitalOcean Droplet) that has to monitor the k8s (from outside of the k8s) with Prometheus & Grafana.
NOTE: I am not allowed to touch & implement monitoring inside the k8s, was told it is fragile or smth.

I wonder if this is even possible ? also wonder if anyone has a docker-compose file that do this that can be shared ?

Comment: without doing anything inside the cluster you might be out of luck. 
there are multiple ways to do this however in general. you can deploy kube-state-metrics inside your cluster, expose the metrics endpoint via an ingress an scrape it from outside. deploy prometheus inside the cluster and use remote-write to push metrics to outside the cluster. but without doing anything inside k8s, there's no monitoring data exposed and therefore no real way to get to that data

Comment: @meaningqo Thank you for the infos! I was told that I would be given kubeconfig yaml file if needed, also able to deploy prometheus inside the cluster!
But since, having another ingress (for metrics scraping from outside) in DigitalOcean is $12, it is more likely that I would have to do the remote-write method.

Comment: & by the way, may I ask if there are articles about doing prometheus remote-write thing ?

Comment: you don't need another ingress-controller. but expose endpoint via ingress object. I don't think that requires additional $ but i'm no expert on digital ocean. 

https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#remote_write
or if you are using the operator: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana-cloud/kubernetes-monitoring/other-methods/prometheus/remote_write_operator/